# Why is one cruiser easier to pedal than the other?

Tags: cruiser

We have two cruisers. Cruise One was purchased about 5 years ago, mostly kept inside, not rusted or anything, just hasn't been ridden much.
Cruiser Two is older; someone gave it to us. It is MUCH easier to pedal than Cruiser One. I rarely even get my blood pumping, even when I pedal uphill.
Meanwhile Cruise One feels like a workout on flat roads.
I've tried examining them to see what the difference is. Same size chain ring, same size everything. Cruise One does have a heavier frame, but not by much.
Any idea?

Comment: use tire pressure gauge, pump both to upper end of the range printed on sidewall, then compare, no "thumb test feels ok"

Comment: We're still waiting on some photos, please.

Answer (score 4):

-brakes rubbing?

-quality of the tyres

-quality of the bearings

Comment: You might add tire pressure, but unless it's really bad tires at a way too low pressure, the tires should not have such a noticeable effect. It's much more likely that the OP's problem is due to a rubbing brake or a bad bearing.

Answer (score 3):

Adding photos of the two bikes might help, but I'd guess that tyre pressure and body fit/position are the two main differences.

The bikes are not the same obviously, so subtle differences can sap one's power.   Weight isn't that big a deal when riding on the flat - it takes a bit longer to get a heavier bike up to the same speed, but keeping it there is a function of resistance from wind/tyres/friction etc.  For example I've got a 25 kg bike that pedals faster on the flat than a 10 kg bike.

If you could add photos, we can go further.

Comment: And even the 25 kg bike will only be a quarter of the total weight when a 75 kg cyclist sits on top of it. Less for heavier persons. (Btw: Heavier bikes/riders have more fun going downhill...)

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica conversely a lighter bike "feels" far faster than the difference should be.  Possibly the placebo effect, but a 7 kg bike feels snappy after a 10 kilo bike.

Answer (score 2):

Criggie and JoeK have offered excellent suggestions.

Other factors to consider.
In working on new bikes out of the box I've found that from the factory most everything on a new bike out is too tight (even bike shop bikes). If the bike was assembled without attention to adjusting front and headset bearings, rear hub, front hub, chain tension and crank bearings they tend to be destructively tight. Your bike might never have been adjusted correctly.

- Hubs should roll smoothly with no play (a little play if the rear hub is a coaster brake).
- Crank should spin smoothly with no play.
- The chain should have about 1/2 inch of deflection (Best to play with this one a little for best fit)

A bike can go from difficult to pedal (even in the rack) to easy to pedal when adjusted correctly.

Comment: Excellent addition to JoeK's answer.